# duplicate each element in a list arbitrary of times

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, numpy

I am wondering how to duplicate each element in a list arbitrary of times, e.g.

```
l = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

the duplicate elements in `l` result in a new list,

```
n = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c']
```

so 'a' has been duplicated 3 times, 'b' once, 'c' twice. The number of duplicates for each element are decided by `numpy.random.poisson` e.g. `numpy.random.poisson(2)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a NumPy based vectorized approach using [`np.repeat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) to create an array -

```
np.repeat(l, np.random.poisson([2]*len(l)))
```

If you need a list as output, append [`.tolist()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tolist.html) there -

```
np.repeat(l, np.random.poisson([2]*len(l))).tolist()
```

If you would like to keep at least one entry for each element, add a clipping there with `np.random.poisson([2]*len(arr)).clip(min=1)`.

Comment: I just realized that `np.random.poisson(2)` may equal to `0`, but I like to keep each element in the list, some elements may be missing if `np.random.poisson([2])` is `0`, how to avoid it?

Comment: @daiyue Added a note to avoid such a case.

Answer (score 1):

Multiply each element in the list with the value returned from `numpy.random.poisson(2)`, `join` it and then feed it to `list`:

```
r = list(''.join(i*random.poisson(2) for i in l))
```

For one run, this randomly results in:

```
['a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c']
```

Since you use `np` either way, I'd go with Divakar's solution (which, for lists larger than your example, executes faster).

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> l = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> n = []
>>> for e in l:
...     n.extend([e] * numpy.random.poisson(2))
... 
>>> n
['a', 'a', 'b', 'c']
```